# ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA has 0 total_pages/used_pages/data_pages for rows having size > 9000 bytes in Azure SQL DB table

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

We have a column xyz with varchar(max). We store long strings in that column. I verified using below query to see how many records have column xyz dataLength > 9000 bytes. the result was 35 as total count.

```
SELECT count(Id) FROM testTable where datalength(xyz) > 9000;
```

I ran below query to look at the total_pages/used_pages/data_pages for ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA and everything is showing as 0. I was expecting few pages since there were around 35 records for which column size itself was greater 9000.

[image]

I read in below articles that rows exceeding size 8kb will use ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA for longer column. So do you guys see any reason why it did not happen in above case?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186981(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://sqlity.net/en/1051/blob-and-row-overflow-storage-internals-row-overflow-data/

Comment: I don't remember the exact details off the top of my head but my assumption would be then that it will show up as LOB_DATA and only show as ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA in the case that the value is less than 8000 bytes but there is no space to store it in the row when adding up the length of all columns

Comment: @MartinSmith I do see LOB _DATA. when you say value < 8000 bytes, is it column value? So in this case since column value > 8 kb, it considered it as LOB_DATA instead of ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA?